# Converting Input Strings Into Dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have tried many times converting input data into another string and then printing it out in the updated version.

```
strings = input("What is the sentence?") # inputs data

words = strings.split() # splits every word into a string
words = { # dictionary
    'swimming': 'swimming pool', 
    'walking': 'pedestrian road'
    'flying': 'airplane'
        }
```

for example: input = 'I am swimming today.'
output = 'swimming pool'

I think this works like classification but have no idea how to apply it to this.

Comment: The first time you assign to *words* you'll get a list of whitespace separated strings from the *strings* variable. You then immediately overwrite it with a dictionary

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and try to **explain** the intent of the code better. For example, you say that when the user inputs `I am swimming today.`, the program output should be `swimming pool`. I assume you mean that this should have something to do with the dictionary, but that is too vague - **what is the rule that tells you** how to get that result? Step by step, how do you want the program to look at the input to figure that out?

Answer (score 0):

Don't overwrite `words` with your dictionary -- instead declare your dictionary separately, and iterate over words to find entries in the dictionary.

```
>>> verb_objects = {
...     'swimming': 'swimming pool', 
...     'walking': 'pedestrian road',
...     'flying': 'airplane',
... }
>>> sentence = "I am swimming today."
>>> [verb_objects[word] for word in sentence.split() if word in verb_objects]
['swimming pool']
```

Comment: We've had this talk before. Questions exist to build a reference library, not to try to guess at what OP wants and solve an idiosyncratic problem.